# Scala: Trait Mixin with Abstract Base Class

Tags: scala, mixins, traits, abstract-base-class

I have an abstract base class (`Base`) that has some stacking traits defined for it (`StackingTrait`).

```
trait Base {
  def foo
}
trait StackingTrait extends Base {
  abstract override def foo { super.foo }
}
```

It would be very convenient to implement a subclass using the following syntax, but this doesn't work because the compiler says that foo needs to be declared with `override` and then with `abstract override` on recompile, which is invalid because `Impl` is a class.

```
class Impl extends Base with StackingTrait {
  def foo {}
}
```

I cannot think of a good reason why such syntax would be disallowed; foo is logically defined with `Impl` so that ordering that stacking occurs in conceptually remains the same.

Note: 
I figured out this workaround that will effectively do the same thing that I want, but the necessity of a helper class makes me want a better solution.

```
class ImplHelper extends Base {
  def foo {}
}
class Impl extends ImplHelper with StackingTrait
```

Why does the desired syntax not compile and is there an elegant solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My understanding is that while the error message may be confusing, the behaviour is correct.
`foo` is declared as `abstract override` in `StackingTrait`, and thus in any concrete class that mixes `StackingTrait` there must be a concrete (not marked as `abstract`) implementation of `foo` **before** `StackingTrait` (relative to the linearization order). This is because `super` refers to the trait just before in the linearization order, so there definitely needs to be a concrete implementation of `foo` before `StackingTrait` is mixed in, or `super.foo` would be nonsensical.

When you do this:

```
class Impl extends Base with StackingTrait {
  def foo {}
}
```

the linearization order is `Base` <- `StackingTrait` <- `Impl`. The only trait before `StackingTrait` is `Base` and `Base` does not define a concrete implementation of `foo`.

But when you do this:

```
traitImplHelper extends Base {
  def foo {}
}
class Impl extends ImplHelper with StackingTrait
```

The linearization order becomes: `Base` <- `ImplHelper` <- `StackingTrait` <- `Impl`
Here `ImplHelper` contains a concrete definition of `foo`, and is definitly **before** `StackingTrait`.

For what is worth, if you had mixed `ImplHelper` after `StackingTrait` (as in `class Impl extends StackingTrait with ImplHelper`) you would again have the same problem and it would fail to compile.

So, this look fairly consistent to me.
I am not aware of a way to make it compile as you intended to. However if you are more concerned about making it easier to write `Impl` (and being able to define `foo` right there without a need for a separate class/trait) than making it easy to write `Base` or `StackingTrait`, you can still do this:

```
trait Base {
  protected def fooImpl
  def foo { fooImpl } 
}
trait StackingTrait extends Base {
  abstract override def foo { super.foo }
}

class Impl extends Base with StackingTrait {
  protected def fooImpl {}
}
```

Just like in the original version you force each concrete class to implement `foo` (in the form of `fooImpl`) and this time it does compile.
The downside here is that while `fooImpl` must not call `super.foo` (it makes no sense and will go into an infinite loop), the compiler won't warn you about it.

Comment: Great answer! I was about to post a question about this very scenario. Thanks!

Comment: I have just encountered this problem, too. The linearization is ultimately right about this but I realized the real world purpose of stacking traits is this: You can do a modification with a stacking trait only to an existing concrete implementation of common abstract class/trait. Ie. have an `abstract class List` and a `trait Mod extends List`. You can't just write `class Foo extends List with Mod`. First, you have to have a concrete List, like `class LinkedList extends List`, then you can write `class Bar extends LinkedList with Mod`. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: I forgot to add that this only concerns traits with `abstract override` methods, to be clear. Without such methods it seems traits can be mixed in freely.

Comment: Have you tried this? https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/self-types.html

Answer (score 0):

Instead of extending the trait you can try to use a self-type as mentioned in the example. 
https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/self-types.html.